# How to use CombineReducers for nested reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to learn react and redux and i try to work on json like this :

```
"profile": {},
"activities": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "components": [
            {"id":1,"name":"test1"},
            {"id":1,"name":"test1"},
            {"id":1,"name":"test1"}
        ],
        "actions": []
    }
]
```

I try to use combine reducers for adding componentReducer and actionsReducer into activity but finaly I get many errors. How do you model a json like this into redux with nesting combineReducers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good explanation at http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html.

Basically:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import profile from './reducers/profile';
import activites from './reducers/activites';

export default createStore(combineReducers({ profile, activies });
```

EDIT:

Oops i misread!

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({
  router, // redux-react-router reducer
    account: combineReducers({
      profile: combineReducers({
         info, // reducer function
         credentials // reducer function
      }),
      billing // reducer function
    }),
    // ... other combineReducers
  })
});
```

From https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/738

Comment: can you show me a real example based on my json, a reducer for activities ? i try but it dosent feet what i need.